# how to Fix Nav and Tab Both

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/L1bns58m/1/

Scripts are programmed to check whether my tab is on the top or not. If top just fixed it by updating/ adding the class sticky.

Code:

```js
// This is my javaScript Code ....
// which will check whether my tab is on the top or not... if top just fixed
// it by updating/ adding the class sticky.
    window.onscroll = function() {cFunction()};

    var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
    var sticky = header.offsetTop;

        function cFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
      }     else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
      }
```

```css
.btn-primary
        {
        font-size:12px;
        }
      .btn-group-justified {
           width:100%;
          }
      .sticky {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .sticky + .content {
      padding-top: 102px;
    }

    .section{
    width:100%;
    }

      }
    }</script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
<!-- MY Tab Code below the NAV Section 

This is My tab bar consisting of bootstrap button group. -->

    <section>
    <div class="container" id="myHeader">
      <div id="no" class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Rates</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">What to Expect</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Our Professionals</a>
        </div>
    
        <div id="yes" class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Reviews</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Recent Bookings</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">FAQs</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Related Blogs</a>
 
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

How to fix both navbar and tab? Actually, I want to fix my tab bar below my Navbar.
 I just tried to change the top from 0 to some +ve value but nothing changed.also used position :fixed.

Comment: @Paulie_D  ... Thanks ...actually, before posting the link without code... I tried the stack snippet but it was showing me the error that code is more & information is less ...So, After trying and trying I hv just divided my code into multiple sections(sry fr this..).. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one, I checked your CSS and didn't find anything related to the classes "nav", "navbar-nav", or anything like that.  Did you finish styling the navbar? I don't see CSS anywhere for that.

```
.btn-primary
    {
    font-size:12px;
    }
  .btn-group-justified {
       width:100%;
      }
  .sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

.section{
width:100%;
}

  }
}</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Also, I know this doesn't answer your question, but your JavaScript gave me an "unexpected end of input error" because apparently when I put it in the console there were a couple brackets missing at the end of the **if...else** code blocks. You might want to make sure you didn't forget those last two closing brackets, if it's working fine then it must just be me...

Comment: Actually , if you will remove the navbar then you will be able to see my buttons tab bar ... I tried to show a better example previously but the community guys started down voting and the stack snippet was  showing me error that more information required etc.. so I Hv reduced the lines of code... thanks fr your response and editing.

Comment: Alright!   I'd try fixing it now but this discussion is outdated now and I've lost track. If I get a chance I'll help later